# How to convert dates to character strings of various formats?

Tags: r, string, date, lubridate

I would like to emphasise straight away that I am asking for the opposite of `lubridate::dmy()` and `lubridate::as_date()` (and similar functions), which convert strings like "31 July 2022", "July 31st, 2022", "31st of July, '22" to a standard datetime format like "2022-07-31" (as shown in the [cheatsheet](https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/lubridate.pdf)).

I want to do the opposite: I already have datetime variables which I wish to convert back to strings such as the above. If `lubridate` can automatically detect such string formats and convert them without errors, it should be able to do the inverse as well? I couldn't figure out which function can be used for this (is there one?).

Of course, it is possible to manually do it by gluing strings from multiple functions, like so:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- today()
x
[1] "2022-07-31"
glue::glue("{day(x)} {month(x, label = T, abbr = F)} {year(x)}")
31 July 2022
```

But I was hoping there might be a function that does this directly, perhaps with a `format =`  specification.

Comment: `format(x, '%d %B %Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:-

```
library(lubridate)
today <- today()
format(today, format = "%d %B %Y")
```

This will give the format that you are looking for.

Comment: I had tried `%M` which failed. `%B` works, thank you. Is there some documentation on the various format specifications? For example, if I would like to produce `"31st of July, 2022"` instead.

Comment: @KarthikThrikkadeeri `%M` means "minute". If you want "month", you should use `%m`. Other identifiers can be searched in `help(strptime)` or `?strptime`. For your example, try `format(x, "%dst of %B, %Y")`.